# Leakage during Celite filtration

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

I'm conducting a synthesis involving crown ether and Pd catalyst.
In many papers, prior to column chromatography, they filter crude mixture through a Celite pad.
I tried to, but leakage of Celite occurred. Referring to this paper : https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo005577d (see General Procedure part), I started the reaction with 10 mL of toluene as solvent, and continued work-up with 60 mL dichloromethane. In some cases the filtrate seemed to contain Celite, and the other cases, once I turn on the vacuum pump, some of Celite powder fell down to the collecting flask. What did I mistake? I used Buchner filter, and almost-fitted filter paper (55mm diameter, 1 μm pore size). Basically I referred to this video : https://youtu.be/oAzScPuZqjU. (In this video, after first filtration to make pad, he washes collecting flask and continues second filtration. Both images I uploaded are about second filtration.)

[image: basic filtration setup] [image: filtrate seems to contain Celite]

Comment: The problem is the "almost fitted" filter paper. Do you have access to sintered glass filters?

Comment: According to Vogel's practical organic chemistry, it says that a filter paper should cover the entire perforate plate, but its diameter should be slightly less than the inside diameter of funnel. so I thought, 'Is the filter paper "too fitted?"', so I tried to cut some of its circumference and filtrated again, but it didn't work. (even before I turn on the vacuum pump, Celite slurry almost fell down.) I have sintered glass filter, but I don't have appropriate-sized filter paper.

Comment: sorry for misleading word, 'almost-fitted' should be corrected to 'almost completely-fitted'.

Comment: The reason that I referred to filter paper in the case of sintered glass filter is in that video, he recommends to use second filter paper to maintain Celite pad unbroken.

Comment: @KrangLee If you are sure that paper fitting isn't an issue, then probably celite particles size is. Are you using Celite 545? Alternatively, make sure you are not rapidly applying vacuum — this might cause some particles to puncture the filter paper.

Comment: Yes, I use Celite 545. I usually follow these steps:
1. put filter paper.
2. wet the paper and turn on vacuum shortly, then turn off.
3. put appropriate amount of Celite.
4. pour enough solvent, and slightly mix.
5. turn on vacuum, make Celite pad.
6. put second filter paper.
7. wet paper.
8. start filtration.

Comment: You mean that at first, I should do filtration without vacuum? (for your information my vacuum pump can't control the power. so whenever I saw some texts saying "When you do filtration, suction gently at first", I couldn't do anything)

Comment: As I remembered just now, it seemed that after I wet the filter paper and then turn on the vacuum, the paper flap up. How do I prevent this? I completely wet the paper aforetime, but once I turn on vacuum, the solvent evaporated quickly and paper flap up.

Comment: If you have a sintered glass filter you do not need a filter paper. Make up the celite/solvent slurry in the filter then apply the suction to form the Celite pad.